window.after() is not working in a for loop?

import random, string, tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

char = string.punctuation + string.ascii_letters
password = ""

def generate():
    global password
    try:
        if var.get() == 0:
            messagebox.showerror("Error","Enter a number higher than 0")
        else:
            for i in range(int(var.get())):
                next_char = random.choice(char)
                password += next_char
            print(password)
            password =""
    except ValueError:
        error()

def error():
    Error_label.pack()
    Error_label.config(fg="red")
    for i in range(5):
        print("hh")
        window.after(1500, lambda : Error_label.config(fg="red"))
        window.after(1500, lambda : Error_label.config(fg="black"))


window = tkinter.Tk()
window.geometry("200x200")

var = tkinter.StringVar(window)

length_entry = tkinter.Entry(window,width=10,textvariable=var)
length_entry.pack()

generate_button = tkinter.Button(window, text="Generate",command=generate,font=("Terminal"))
generate_button.pack(pady=50)

Error_label = tkinter.Label(window,text="Error",font=("Terminal"))

window.mainloop()



in the error() function the, the program must change the label color to red and wait 1.5 second then change it to black and repeat this 5 times according to the for loop, but somehow the program is not waiting and doing it directly and i knew that with printing.
i tried doing it with out the for loop and it worked but i wanted to know why its not working in the for loop .

after does not block.

"the program must change the label color to red and wait 1.5 second then change it to black and repeat this 5 times" - what do you think it should mean to "repeat" doing something after "waiting for 1.5 seconds"? I can think of at least two ways to interpret that: wait 1.5 seconds, then do one thing, then wait another 1.5 seconds and do the next thing, etc; or - wait 1.5 seconds, then do everything.

When you use after() in a loop, it doesn't pause the execution of the loop. Instead, it schedules the function to be called after the specified time, but the loop continues without waiting for it.
You can try this:
def error(count=5):
    if count > 0:
        if count % 2 == 0:
            Error_label.config(fg="red")
        else:
            Error_label.config(fg="black")
        Error_label.pack()
        window.after(1500, lambda: error(count - 1))
    else:
        Error_label.pack_forget()


When you use window.after() in a loop all the shceduled events are executed at pretty much the same time. So to change it gradually you need to add a count. Try this code:
def error(count=5):
if count > 0:
    Error_label.config(fg="red")
    window.after(1500, lambda: error(count - 1))
    window.after(3000, lambda: Error_label.config(fg="black"))

